# Format timestamp from MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a mysql query that has a column CreationDate in the format of "timestamp".  Example:

```
2013-03-27 18:32:45
```

I would like for the sql query to format it in this fashion (12hr format with seconds):

```
Friday 3/28/2013 12:52:34 PM
```

I would like to handle this at the sql level rather than php or .js, etc.

Query:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.CreationDate, a.Content, a.Type, u.Nickname
FROM Announcements a 
INNER JOIN Accounts u ON a.FromAccountID = u.AccountID
WHERE a.Status  = '1' AND u.Status = '1'
ORDER BY a.ID DESC
```

Comment: MySQL's [`Date_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to use [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT a.ID, 
  date_format(a.CreationDate, '%W %m/%d/%Y %l:%i %p') CreationDate, 
  a.Content, 
  a.Type, 
  u.Nickname 
FROM Announcements a 
INNER JOIN Accounts u 
  ON a.FromAccountID = u.AccountID 
WHERE a.Status = '1' 
  AND u.Status = '1' 
ORDER BY a.ID DESC
```

The MySQL docs will show what specifiers you will use to get the format that you want (See [SQL Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9720)).

If you want to keep seconds, then you will use:

```
date_format(a.CreationDate, '%W %m/%d/%Y %r')
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the seconds in this Friday 3/28/2013 12:52:02 PM

Comment: @user1157800 See my edit, you will use `'%W %m/%d/%Y %r %p'` as the format

Comment: I am sorry but how can I keep 12 hour format with AM/PM respectfully?

Comment: @user1157800 Sorry I used the wrong one `'%W %m/%d/%Y %r %p'`

Answer (score 1):

`DATE_FORMAT(a.CreationDate,'%W %c/%e/%Y %h:%i %p')`