# convert unix date to 24 hour ISO format

Tags: sql, presto

I'm using date_trunc to convert unix time to a more readable format. However, the value for 'hour' returns the year and hour with trailing 0s. I would like the format to only display hh:mm in military time. How can I achieve that?

```
SELECT
    actor_id AS SRT_ID,
    shift_date,
    DATE_TRUNC('hour', from_unixtime(shift_start)) AS login,
    DATE_TRUNC('hour', from_unixtime(shift_end)) AS logout
FROM
    fct_rep_schedule_details
WHERE
    ds BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-01-15'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

For example, I expect the output to be `13:00` instead of `2019-01-22 13:00:00.000`.

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format timestamp from MYSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690575/format-timestamp-from-mysql-query)

Comment: @tony updated tag. prestodb

Comment: I have a vibe that  `date_trunc` is doing something else as you are expecting. DATE_TRUNC is used for truncation, not formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to truncate the date.  You want to extract the hour/time.  You can extract the time using `cast()`:

```
SELECT actor_id AS SRT_ID,
       shift_date,
       DATE_TRUNC('hour', from_unixtime(shift_start)) AS login,
       DATE_TRUNC('hour', from_unixtime(shift_end)) AS logout,
       CAST(from_unixtime(shift_start) as time) AS login_hh,
       CAST(from_unixtime(shift_end) as time) AS logout_hh,
FROM fct_rep_schedule_details
WHERE ds BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-01-15';
```

If you want to control the formatting of the time, use `to_char()`:

```
SELECT actor_id AS SRT_ID,
       shift_date,
       DATE_TRUNC('hour', from_unixtime(shift_start)) AS login,
       DATE_TRUNC('hour', from_unixtime(shift_end)) AS logout,
       TO_CHAR(from_unixtime(shift_start), 'HH:MI') AS login_hh,
       TO_CHAR(from_unixtime(shift_end), 'HH:MI') AS logout_hh,
FROM fct_rep_schedule_details
WHERE ds BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-01-15';
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried using cast but the result returns 10:30:00.000. Is there any way to only display the time format as 10:30 in military?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of truncating the date, you want to format the date. You should be able to format the time with the following query:

```
SELECT
    actor_id AS SRT_ID,
    shift_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(shift_start), '%H:%i') AS login,
    DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(shift_end), '%H:%i')  AS logout
FROM
    fct_rep_schedule_details
WHERE
    ds BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-01-15'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

where `%H` translates to the hour in 00 .. 23 and `%i` to minutes according to the [prestoDB documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)